# Wildcards in XPath attributes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have this:

```
//th[@style='border-bottom-color: #ce9c00; text-align: left; line-height: 25px;
```

I want to make it select any color, like this in regex;

```
//th[@style='border-bottom-color: #......; text-align: left; line-height: 25px;
```

How do I do this? I'm using C# and Html Agility Pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use matches() xpath function and give it a regular expression like this.

```
//th[matches(@salary,'^border-bottom-color: #[0-9a-fA-F]{6}; text-align: left; line-height: 25px$')]
```

Note: I have given [0-9a-fA-F] because color takes hex decimal value, you can simply use .(dot) in place if that.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath 1.0 string functions `substring`, `contains`, etc, e.g.:

```
//th[starts-with(@style, 'border-bottom-color: #')
    and contains(@style, '; text-align: left; line-height: 25px;')]
```